# Upgrade TexLive from 2012 to 2013 with Ubuntu

Tags: latex, paths

I have downloaded TeXLive 2013 and installed it as explained on the developer's website. At the end in the terminal I got the following message:

> Add /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/info to INFOPATH.
>   Add /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/man to MANPATH
>     (if not dynamically found).
>
> Most importantly, add /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux
>   to your PATH for current and future sessions.

What should I do? Furthermore when compiling my documents, `emacs` is still using the version 2012 of TeXLive, what should I do to use the 2013 version (I already removed the TeXLive package 2012 with the Ubuntu Software Center), I'm running Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which I will present here for those in the same case as me.

Edit your `.bashrc` and add the following line

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

then in your terminal enter

```
source .bashrc
```

and as soon as you will open a new terminal and launch your editor you will run TeXLive-2013.

Comment: put it in your .profile and you will have it available even for applications launched from the desktop environment...(after login-logout)